# Can I authenticate with OAuth Authorization server by passing username and password in Authorization header?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization, implicit

In case of OAuth 2.0 authorization code and implicit flow cases, on hitting the Authorization Url user is redirected to OAuth providers login page.

To avoid showing up the OAuth providers page in my application, can i make user to enter username and password in text fields and pass them as Authorization header of authorization Url and get back access_token from OAuth provider and use it for further requests ?

Is it legal, valid and feasible ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it legal, valid and feasible ?

No. Not with the flow you are using right now. **Implicit flow** is not built for this purpose, so you cannot do it.

But, OAuth 2.0 provide you a dedicated flow for your requirement.

**[4.3.  Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)**

> The resource owner password credentials grant type is suitable in
> cases where the resource owner has a trust relationship with the
> client, such as the device operating system or a highly privileged application.

As described in protocol, in this flow, your end user(resource owner) provide their credentials to client application. Client application call token endpoint with resource owner credentials to obtain access tokens.

Flow overview (From [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749))

[image]

Token request request (From [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749))

[image]

As specification mention, this flow is there to support old systems which are unable to fully utilise OAuth 2.0. For example clients which use basic authentication.